# How to remove shiny spots from photography print on wood?

Tags: printing, prints

I had a photograph I took printed directly onto wood with UV Ink through an online service.

The result of the print is beautiful, but all of the dark/black ink reflects light, while the light colors have no shine and show the natural grain of the wood. This results in shiny or glossy "spots" in the areas with dark ink.

Any advice on how to remove this shine and mattify the print? I cannot have it reprinted.

[image: Print on wood: UV Ink has shine only on black ink.]

Answer (score 4):

> Any advice on how to remove this shine and mattify the print?

There are a number of matte-finish sealers on the market, many in spray cans (which would be easiest to apply). One example is [Krylon 1309 Gallery Series Artist and Clear Coatings Aerosol](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004BPXI7W). I haven't used that particular product, but the description leads one to believe that it might help protect the image from moisture and UV as well as cutting the shine.

As with any untried product, you should test it on a sample before going to town on any important projects.